# How to resize high resolution tif images efficiently and quickly?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, image-resizing, tiff, javax.imageio

I am working on a project where I have users uploading print quality high resolution tif images and I need to create a lower resolution web quality preview for the user if/when they come back to view what they uploaded.

Currently I have a working solution to resize these images using `ImageIO.read` and `ImageIO.write` but it is taking up to 15 minutes to modify and save these preview images. I am wondering if there is a better solution that would take less time to complete. Or is this a RAM issue that I am experiencing?

Comment: What sizes (typical w x h) are your input images? How large are the files? What is the size (w x h) of the low res preview you are generating? What is the file format of the preview? Do you a more accurate definition of "web quality"? I know of a few ways to speed this up, but what is better depends on some of these factors.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what libraries you're using, but you can do this in two passes.  If you're cutting the resolution by half in width and height, then simply take every other pixel and create a quick image from that.  It will be low quality, but you should be able to do this very quickly even on large images.  Later, perhaps with a workflow automation system, you can "slow cook" a better-quality derez and take some time to do it well.